# Auto-scrolling Chrome's DevTools console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Since its inception few years back, Chrome has become a de-facto IDE for web development. I've been using it's Canary(Version 28.0.1464.0) channel for quite a bit and been happy as a clam. 
Only issue that keeps bothering me is the lack of ability to have the DevTools console pane, auto scroll to the last message added. I understand that many folks would prefer to have the current behavior. However I was wondering: Does anyone knows how (if even possible with the current release) to flip the switch and have the console auto-scroll?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a great feature request.

http://chromiumbugs.appspot.com/

Comment: Great question, but this appears more to be a bug, not a feature, no? Why would "many folks [] prefer to have the current behavior"? Virtually every console in existence by default autoscrolls to new content.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Clearing the console and scrolling the bar down to the bottom didn't work for me.

The problem was that I had **zoomed out** DevTools.

**Solution:**

1. Focus the DevTools, e.g. by clicking on the console's `>` prompt
2. Hit **`Ctrl-0`** (zero) on Windows, or **`Cmd-0`** (zero) on OS X, to restore the default font-size

Hopefully then auto-scroll to bottom will start working again!

Thanks to this guy for pointing it out:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=161646#c5

Comment: This is a pretty silly problem that I've had for about 4 months, but it's one of those things you don't verbalize in a google-search...  All webdevs should know this! Thanks.

Comment: I'm specifically having problems with large amounts of log messages in an uncollapsed group only auto-scrolling one line for the whole group.  This made my problem a little better (I had no idea my console was not default zoom)

Comment: For those that still had this problem after checking their zoom, I had to close the console bar to get devtools to auto-scroll. See 'x' bottom right http://f.cl.ly/items/2p3W0t0F031E3x2i361x/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-28%20at%2010.04.48%20PM.png

Comment: To be able to reset the zoom, I had to undock dev tools as a separate window and do it within that window. Otherwise `CTRL+0` was acting the the website I was visiting.

Answer (score 15):

## One Reason why it's happening:

Logging of HTML elements into the console makes the console view lose the last console message.

## How to solve it:

Instead of doing something like this:

`console.log("Some logging message:", html_element)`

try this (wrapped the messages with brackets)

`console.log(["Some logging message:", html_element])`

Comment: Changing my console.log("label", value) to console.log("label " +  value) got my autoscroll back on, thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 4):

It drove me crazy too and I found the solution here:

[Google Chrome follow developer console logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247028/google-chrome-follow-developer-console-logging)

> With the console open, drag the scroll bar down to the bottom of the
>   window and release it. It should tail the output for you.

It does not matter if you have the console docked or not.

Working for me on a osx 10.8.5 and chrome 31

Comment: I've been having issues with this on 49 also.

Comment: Also having issues on Chrome 49 but only on certain pages.

Comment: Also also have the issue on Chrome 49.

Comment: Get's really annoying when you're working with React and logging each state change...

Comment: No help with Chrome 49

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome version 29.0.1547.76 m, it auto-scrolls when you undock the console. It stops auto-scrolling if you click on the console, then you'll have to clear the console before auto-scroll will be ready to start again.

The "Undock into separate window." button is the bottom-left most button of the console.

Answer (score 3):

For me I've noticed that the autoscroll stopped when the console showed a warning so I've filtered out the warnings and all is good:

[image: screenshot of console log]

Answer (score 0):

For me the only solution that worked was:

1. click F1 (settings)
2. At the bottom  restore defaults and reload.

None of the above worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution in Chrome 49+

Go Dev-tools/ Settings /

"Console tab"

x Preserve log upon navigation.

Done!