# Chrome dev tools stops autoscroll of console when logging a function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When a `console.log` happens and you have the console scrolled to the bottom, Chrome automatically keeps scrolling down as more and more things gets logged.

However, if a function gets passed to `console.log` this automatic scrolling stops and you have to go to the dev tools window and manually scroll it to the bottom again. See screenshot:

[image: chrome dev tools]

Does anybody know a workaround or plugin that helps this?

(Tested in Chrome 46.0.2490.86)

**Edit:** for any kind of workaround, I'd like to keep the nice functionality in Chrome that if I click on the function in the Console, Chrome opens up the file where the function is declared and focuses on the function in the 'Sources' tab.

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832519/auto-scrolling-chromes-devtools-console/37297375#37297375