# Google Chrome Console doesn't auto scroll down

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Why? When I press F5 with the console opened, most of the time it won't auto scroll to the last line, making me having to MANUALLY scroll down everytime. A pain in the neck.

Comment: I have same... Really annoying

Answer (score 8):

Unzoom: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24965488

This worked for me even if I was 100% certain I wasn't zoomed in